# Explicit language tags should override implicit ones

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

For example, code in a question tagged both [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) will still be given C# highlighting by default. Might it be better to make specific language tags override implicit ones if there’s only one?

Comment: They can be overridden using `<!-- language: lang-your-preferred-lang-name -->`

Comment: @hjpotter92: I know. This is a convenience. (I mean, we don’t really *need* tag-based language detection in the first place — but it’s nice.)

Comment: what happened to your reputation ?

Comment: @Lucifer [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160410/rynah?tab=bounties&sort=offered) happened.

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin' what a nice doner, he is !!!

Comment: Congrats, by the way, for your new diamond.

Comment: Congratulations @minitech, finally you got diamond :)

Comment: And nice to see you're minitech again, too :D (Nothing wrong with rynah, but minitech was a landmark on SO.)